# Set up custom subdomain for Jekyll Blog hosted in Github Pages

Tags: github, subdomain, jekyll, host, github-pages

I created a Jekyll-powered blog and am hosting it with GitHub Pages.

Now, I want to set up a subdomain (blog.example.com), but can't make it work.

I have added a CNAME file with the text: blog.example.com. And I have added two A records in my Dreamhost account for the subdomain, both pointing to 204.232.175.78, provided by GitHub.

Any idea about what the missing part is, or if I'm doing something incorrectly?

Comment: ¿Cuánto tiempo has esperado desde la modificación?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The setup is different for domains like `example.com` and sub-domains like `blog.example.com`.

#### In case of a sub-domain: blog.example.com

1. Go to **Domains | Manage Domains** in your webpanel
2. Locate `blog.example.com`, click **Delete** in the **Actions** column
3. Wait 10 minutes, and then click the **DNS** link below `example.com`
4. Add a `CNAME` record:

   - **Name** = `blog`
   - **Type** = `CNAME`
   - **Value** = `yourusername.github.io.` (yes there is a `.` at the end!)

#### In case of a domain: example.com

1. Go to **Domains | Manage Domains** in your webpanel
2. Locate `example.com`, click **Edit** in the **Actions** column and switch to **DNS only** hosting (it's at the bottom)
3. Go back to **Domains | Manage Domains** in your webpanel
4. Click the **DNS** link below `example.com`
5. Add an `A` record:

   - **Name** = (blank, nothing)
   - **Type** = `A`
   - **Value** = `185.199.108.153` (GitHub, from [this page](https://help.github.com/articles/tips-for-configuring-an-a-record-with-your-dns-provider/#configuring-an-a-record-with-your-dns-provider))
6. Add a `CNAME` record:

   - **Name** = `www`
   - **Type** = `CNAME`
   - **Value** = `yourusername.github.io.` (yes there is a `.` at the end!)

(Yes, you need both the `A` and `CNAME` records in this case.)

Btw, the only reason I know this is because I did the same thing last weekend. I was quite lost, but the helpful support guys helped me half way, and I figured out the rest. This procedure works for me, I needed both cases so I tested both.

Comment: Janos, Yes! Thank you, this worked perfectly. I had tried to up vote it but apparently I still can't, and I didn't know I could respond to comments. But anyways, thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there any way to do both? ie your root url is example.com, which shows example.github.io (you have a repo called example.github.io and your username is example) AND blog.example.com forwards to a project's gh-pages branch (you have a repo called blog that is available at example.github.io/blog).

Comment: @chandlervdw I think all you have to do (in Dreamhost) is go: Add New Domain / Sub-Domain -> scroll to the bottom -> type the sub-domain and host DNS only -> follow the settings above for setting CNAME

Comment: Thanks, just FYI make sure you have any DNS redirects disabled on the domain too. I had a redirect and kept getting an error when trying to add the www CNAME

Comment: Looks like the new IPs are 192.30.252.153 and 192.30.252.154, see [here](https://help.github.com/articles/tips-for-configuring-an-a-record-with-your-dns-provider/)

Comment: Is it just me or does GIthub really fail to provide any information about the apex domain case needing the CNAME record as well? Thank you @janos for making this clear

Answer (score 2):

Because of the way DNS records are cached across the internet, these sorts of changes can take a few hours to take effect. It looks like the address you provided resolves correctly now.