# Two jekyll blogs on the same GitHub page

Tags: git, github, jekyll

I have a jekyll blog at https://github.com/alkamid/alkamid.github.io/ that is working fine under http://alkamid.com. I would like to add another blog that would be available at http://alkamid.com/travel.

Following [these instructions](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/) I created a `gh-pages` branch and added `baseurl: /travel` to my `_config.yml`. I then pushed the branch to my github repo and expected to see the new blog at alkamid.com/travel, but all I get is a 404.

Does this setup make sense at all? If so, what should I do more to achieve the desired effect?

PS Someone [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20479904/set-up-custom-subdomain-for-jekyll-blog-hosted-in-github-pages#comment33910148_20483041) the same question in a comment to another question, but the answer below it is not clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`alkamid.github.io` is a user repository, github pages looks for file to publish in `master` branch. Any additionnal `gh-pages` branch will be ignored.

To achieve your goal : just create a `travel` repository and simply push code for you second blog in `gh-pages` branch.

[See github pages documentation about this particular problem](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/).

Comment: Thanks. I totally misunderstood the docs about `gh-pages`. I thought we were only allowed one "GitHub Page" per account.

Comment: What should I then do about CNAME? The blog works, but I get e-mails from github about "CNAME already taken: alkamid.com"

Comment: CNAME only in alkamid.github.io all other repository will inherit.